# Evaluating conditional expression in flycheck syntax checker command

Tags: flycheck

I'd like the `:command` of a flycheck checker to depend on the file extension of the input.

For example:

- for `.tex` files run the command `foo --format latex file.tex`
- for any other file extension run the command `foo --format text file.txt`

I've tried:

`` :command ("foo" "--format"
    `(if (string= "tex" (file-name-extension source-inplace))
        "latex"
        "text")
    source-inplace) ``

Which returns:

```
flycheck-define-command-checker: Invalid command argument (\‘ (if (string= "tex" (file-name-extension source-inplace)) "latex" "text")) in syntax checker textlint
```

Which is thrown [from flycheck](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/blob/master/flycheck.el#L4908) when executing [flycheck-command-argument-p](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/blob/master/flycheck.el#L4745).

Is it possible to achieve what I'm attempting? i.e the command string passed to `:command` being determined by the file extension of the file being checked by flycheck?

For context, the solution was required for implementing a textlint flycheck checker: https://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~rs46/posts/2018-12-29-textlint-flycheck.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `eval` (credit: [flycheck gitter](https://gitter.im/flycheck/flycheck?at=5c2367ddab910e7d3ad55787)):

```
:command ("foo" "--format"
    (eval (if (string= "tex" (file-name-extension buffer-file-name))
                "latex"
               "text"))
    source-inplace)
```